# Undefined variables and invalid data types after trying to install crud-view after crud and cakephp 3.4.11

Tags: cakephp, crud, cakephp-3.x

I'm at a loss here and hopefully someone can help.  I'm very very new to frameworks in general, let alone CakePHP but I think I can get through this once I'm beyond this issue.  It seems like a very simple config problem, but I have no idea where I could have gone wrong. Apologies for terminology gaffes, I'm still learning. Ok, the setup:

Starting from a clean debian 8 system with `PHP 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2`, I followed the CakePHP installation instructions.  Everything went smoothly with `composer`. I followed the tutorial project of the [bookmark tutorial app](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html) and everything was good. I installed the `crud` package from FriendsOfCake, and again, everything looked good, database interaction was fine, crud operations were a success.

I added `crud-view` with `BootstrapUI` and `Search` as well, and started following the `crud-view` instructions to turn this into a bootstrap-enabled ui.  This is where the issue happened.  In the `src/Controller/AppController.php` file, I went to add the code that the installation instructions say to add.  In troubleshooting, I did this process one line at a time to see if I could determine where the issue happens (I know that's not really the most logical way with frameworks, but I'm old school).  Adding the `loadComponent` lines to the `initialize()` function did not generate any problems.  When I add the `if` statement blurb to the `beforeRender` callback, that's when things bork.  Here's the contents of my `AppController.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete',
                'Crud.Lookup',
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                // New listeners that need to be added:
                'CrudView.View',
                'Crud.Redirect',
                'Crud.RelatedModels',
                // If you need searching. Generally it's better to load these
                // only in the controller for which you need searching.
                'Crud.Search',
                'CrudView.ViewSearch',
            ]
        ]);

        /*
         * Enable the following components for recommended CakePHP security settings.
         * see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html
         */
        //$this->loadComponent('Security');
        //$this->loadComponent('Csrf');
    }

    /**
     * Before render callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null|void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    if ($this->viewBuilder()->className() === null) {
            $this->viewBuilder()->className('CrudView\View\CrudView');
        }
    }
}
```

The very last `if` statement there is the addition that causes the breaking, because it's the thing that seems to be roping in crud-view. Since the instructions were a little unclear, I tried it with and without the blurb above it manipulating the type in the response. I didn't think that would be the problem.  When I go to the page, I see this:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: siteTitle [ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp, line 24]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: disableSidebar [ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp, line 42]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: sidebarNavigation [ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Element/sidebar.ctp, line 2]

    Notice (8): Undefined variable: sidebarNavigation [ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Element/sidebar.ctp, line 10]

    Notice (8): Undefined variable: actionConfig [ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Element/sidebar.ctp, line 12]

    Invalid data type, must be an array or \ArrayAccess instance. InvalidArgumentException
    Documentation API

    If you want to customize this error message, create src/Template/Error/error500.ctp
    toggle vendor stack frames
        ⟩ Cake\Utility\Hash::get ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Element/sidebar.ctp, line 12
        ⟩ include CORE/src/View/View.php, line 1025
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->_evaluate CORE/src/View/View.php, line 986
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->_render CORE/src/View/View.php, line 1372
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->_renderElement CORE/src/View/View.php, line 513
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->element ROOT/vendor/friendsofcake/crud-view/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp, line 51
        ⟩ include CORE/src/View/View.php, line 1025
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->_evaluate CORE/src/View/View.php, line 986
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->_render CORE/src/View/View.php, line 657
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->renderLayout CORE/src/View/View.php, line 615
        ⟩ Cake\View\View->render CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 623
        ⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->render CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 125
        ⟩ Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 93
        ⟩ Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch CORE/src/Http/BaseApplication.php, line 78
        ⟩ Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php, line 59
        ⟩ Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
        ⟩ Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke CORE/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 92
        ⟩ Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 51
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Runner->run CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 80
        ⟩ Cake\Http\Server->run ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

And so on down the line.  It looks like I'm missing something very, very simple, but trying to trace back through code following that `siteTitle` variable, for example, cost me a lot of time.  I'm hoping someone can glance at this and go "oh, you didn't throw this simple variable in this file". Thanks so much in advance, and thanks for letting me know where I might be going wrong with this question, also.

Comment: I haven't used this plugin, but Googling `crudview sitetitle` turned up a page about [site title configuration](https://crud-view.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general-configuration/site-title-options.html) which might be helpful? There are other pages there as well about sidebars, etc.

Comment: Yeah I'd seen this, and it looks like a way to change the site title in an individual view as necessary, from what the default would be.  The default clearly isn't in the right place, or isn't being passed properly, or something, and that's the issue I'm looking to resolve.  Thanks! I appreciate the response.

Comment: From that page: "If not set, it will fallback to the following alternative: `Configure::read('CrudView.siteTitle')`". So it would seem that you can put your defaults into a CrudView key in the overall site configuration.